# How to add a barbuttonitem to root viewcontroller when init a new navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to add an rightbarbuttonitem to a root view controller's navbar when I init a navigationcontroller.So custom view controller is not in navigationcontroller, next will be.
my code is:

```
        TipsViewController *tipsView = [[TipsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TipsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tipsView];
        self.loginViewDelegate = tipsView;
        UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[navigationController navigationItem] init];
        UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"load" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
        [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
        [loginViewDelegate passRegistrationResult:str];
        [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
        [tipsView release];
        [navigationController release];
```

I try this but not work...

Answer (score 0):

The api presentModalViewController:animated:
Its first param is UIViewController and UINavigationController is UIViewController's subclass.
So,cannot directly present a UINavigationController but you can present a UIViewController and add UINavigationBar and UIBarbuttonItem to it manually or use Interface Builder.

Hopes it can help you despite I'm not very sure ~ :)